# Как сделать выборку дерева с лимитом на детей в postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

В таблице присутствуют поля *id*, *parent_id*, *depth*.

Допустим имеются такие данные:

```
1, nil, 1
2, 1, 2
3, 1, 2
4, 1, 2
5, 4, 3
6, 4, 3
```

Мне нужно выбрать дерево с лимитом на выбор количества детей и уровней (*depth*). То есть получить например такой результат (`limit child 1, depth <= 3`)

дерево *id*s:

```
1
  4
    5
```

Это возможно сделать sql запросом в postgresql?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+recursive смотрите примеры рекурсивных запросов. во второй части проверяете уровень вложенности заведя соотв. поле

Comment: дело в том что в рекурсивных запросах нельзя задавать лимит на количество детей

Comment: Ну при желании все можно сделать. вопрос в том, почему вы в примере взяли на втором уровне именно запись 4 (с максимальным среди детей id), а на третьем уровне запись 5 (с минимальным). По какому критерию вы выбираете по какой ветви надо пойти

Comment: я хочу сделать систему комментирования как на reddit. в примере я взял произвольную последовательность, что демонстрирует реальный use case если использовать сортировку например по полю score

Comment: я не знаю что такое reddit и в данный момент знать не хочу. Приведите данные, по которым можно было бы однозначно сказать почему выбран именно такой путь. И кстати, что такое depth, неужели она храниться в исходной таблице ? Она же должна динамически вычисляться ...

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению по данным в вопросе невозможно понять, почему были выбраны именно те записи, которые приведены в ожидаемом результате. Так же не ясно зачем в таблице присутствует поле depth, ведь глубина наследования данных должна определяться динамически, на основании наследования. Предположим (по вашим комментариям), что в таблице есть поле `score` и что "первым" наследником надо считать наследника с максимальным score. Так же предположим, что в исходной таблице нет поля depth и нам его надо определять. Имя исходной таблицы `TabX`. Тогда запрос получается таким:

```
with Recursive Q(id,depth) as(
   select id, 1 from TabX where parent_id is null
  union all
   select Src.id, Q.depth+1
     from Q, Src
    where Q.depth<3 and Src.parent_id=Q.id
),
Src(id,parent_id) as(
  select *
    from (
     select id,parent_id,
            row_number() over(partition by parent_id order by score desc) child_num
       from TabX
    ) A where child_num<=1
)

select * from Q
```

Сначала, в блоке `Src` мы нумеруем все дочерние записи с одним родителем подряд и выбираем из них только первые (в заданной сортировке) номера. После этого в рекурсивном блоке строим обычное дерево из этих, уже отфильтрованных записей. При этом не забывая считать уровень вложенности и в условии рекурсивного блока, прекращаем выборку когда глубина достигнет заданной.

Блоки `WITH` расположены немного не логично, потому как такое требование postrgesql - рекурсивный блок должен быть первым. Но это ничуть не мешает нам обращаться из этого блока к записям  выборки написанной ниже.